Realizing rational numbers as proportions of some arithmetical progression
For any positive integer $m$, let $[m] = \{1, 2, \dots, m\}$. My question is whether the following claim is true: for any finite set $\{r_1, r_2, \dots, r_n\}$ of positive rational numbers such that $\sum_{i=1}^n r_i = 1$, there is $m$ and a partition $\{A_1, A_2, \dots, A_n\}$ of $[m]$ such that each $$r_i = \frac{\sum_{x \in A_i} x}{\sum_{x \in [m]} x}.$$
I noticed that when we only have two rational numbers $\{r_1, r_2\}$, we can always choose a large enough $m$ to clear out the denominators of $r_1$ and $r_2$ and then greedily choose a set $A_1$ for $r_1$ (start from $m$ to $1$ and keep adding them to $A_1$ until the sum of them reach $m(m+1)/2 \cdot r_1$. By a careful discussion of possible cases, I think the same greedy idea can deal with three rationals. But I don't see how to approach this problem in general (or inductively). Any ideas or references would be much appreciated!

Nice question! The answer is "yes", though I may not have the best proof here.
To motivate this solution, start with the related problem where we have $r_1=r_2=\cdots=r_n=\frac{1}{n}$. For this, we need to find an $m$ such that we can find a partition $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n$ of $[m]$ in which the sum of every $A_i$ is equal.
Fortunately, this is easy: we just take $m=2n$ and make $A_i=\{i,2n+1-i\}$. The idea is to "add" these together to solve the main question.

Returning to the original problem, if we say $r_i=\frac{p_i}{Q}$ (where $Q$ is the lowest common denominator of $\left\{r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_n\right\}$), we use the above result to construct a valid partition with $m=2Q$. Explicitly, we let
$$A_1=\left\{1,2,\ldots,p_1\right\}\cup \left\{2Q,2Q-1,\ldots,2Q+1-p_1\right\}$$
then
$$A_2=\left\{p_1+1,p_1+2,\ldots,p_1+p_2\right\}\cup \left\{2Q-p_1,2Q-p_1-1,\ldots,2Q+1-p_1-p_2\right\}$$
and so on.

For example, let's take $\left\{r_1,r_2,r_3\right\}=\left\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{5},\frac{3}{10}\right\}=\left\{\frac{5}{10},\frac{2}{10},\frac{3}{10}\right\}$.
In this case $Q=10$ so we take $m=20$ to get $A_1=\{1,2,3,4,5,16,17,18,19,20\}$, $A_2=\{6,7,14,15\}$, $A_3=\{8,9,10,11,12,13\}$ with sums (respectively) $105$, $42$ and $63$; the sum of $[m]$ is $210$ so this partition works.

I also noticed the structured solution for the simple $r_i = r_j$ case, but didn't persist... Thank you so much for the quick and detailed answer!

My initial thought was that this would be a rabbit-hole that possibly also involved pigeon-holes, but it seems not. It'd be interesting to know how small $m$ can actually be.
